# Does assigning a function handler in JavaScript create a copy or just a reference?

Tags: javascript, reference, copy

I'd like to make sure that I can use a function handler without generating a copy every time I assigned it to a handler.

I have a class with a handler such as:

```
snapwebsites.Editor.prototype._somePrivateFunctionHandler = function(e) { ... }
```

Then I read a blob from a file I just received from a Drag & Drop:

```
...
.on("drop", function(e)
{
    // [...snip...] -- I have tests and loop through all the files and
    //                 do this on each file:
    r = new FileReader;
    r.onload = snapwebsites.Editor.prototype._somePrivateFunctionHandler;
    r.readAsArrayBuffer(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0])
}
...
```

When I assign the _somePrivateFunctionHandler function to the onload handler of the FileReader, am I creating a full copy of the function or just a reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a reference. To demonstrate:

```
var xyz = function() {};
var abc  = xyz;
xyz.someproperty = 1;
abc.someproperty; /=> 1
```

Comment: Hmmm... I suppose that means xyz is assigned an object of type function then?

Comment: Everything 'inherits' from Object in js. Try `xyz instanceof Object` or `abc instanceof Object`. The type of abc/xyz indeed is 'function'